# How to change field or update fast in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Document is this

```
{title:"here", lat:123.4512, lng:36.3423, time:"2011-01-02"}
```

i want chane Document like this

```
{title:"here", {latlng: {lat:123.4512, lng:36.3423}}, time:"2011-01-02"}
```

so i will try this by mongodb console.

```
db.coll.find().forEach(function(u){
  u.latlng = {"lat":u.lat, "lng":u.lng};
  db.coll.save(u);
  db.coll.update(u, {$unset:{"map_x1":1, "map_y1":1}});
})
```

but it's very slow T.T

i think another solution

```
db.coll.find().forEach(function(u){
  db.coll.update(u, {{"latlng" : {"lat":u.lat, "lng":u.lng}}, $unset:{"lat":1, "lng":1}});
})
```

but i can't run it. because first solution is still running ....

do you have any fast solution like this job?

Answer (score 10):

Your second query is broken since it'll overwrite the entire document, use $set :

```
db.coll.find().forEach(function(u){
  db.coll.update(u, {$set:{"latlng" : {"lat":u.lat, "lng":u.lng}}, $unset:{"lat":1, "lng":1}});
})
```

This'll be at least twice as fast as your original attempt since there you're updating the same document twice, which is not necessary.

Comment: How does mongo handle such commands? I guess it does some kind of lazy evaluation and updates the documents in one scan of the collection? Or does it have to search again for the document and then update it? The second method would need a 0(n^2) complexity for updating the whole collection, so I hope it's not what happens. But is there any official documentation about this?